# Syntax and usage of DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

While solving differential equations with Mathematica I got into this excercise:

Consider pendulum of length $l$ and $m=1$ affected by $g=9.80665 m/s^2$. The oscillation point of this pendulum isn't fixed but rather moves on the vertical axis with freq $\nu$ and amplitude $a$. let $\phi(t)$ be the amplitude of oscillation then it satisfies the equation

$\ddot\phi(t) = - \frac{g + a\nu^2 cos(\nu t)}{l} Sin(\phi(t))$

(a) Define a function that allows to obtain the solution $\phi(t)$ in terms of the parameters $(a, \nu , l)$ given initial condition $\phi(0)=x$
and $\dot\phi(0)=y$

(b) Let $l=1, a=0$ and given the boundary conditions

- $x=0, y=0.001$;
- $x= \pi/2 , y=0.001;$
- $x = \pi , y= 0.001;$
- $x= \pi , y=0;$

Plot the 4 solution.

```
sol[l_, a_, v_, k_, j_, param_] := Module[
  {grav = 9.80665},
  pend = DSolve[{y''[t] == -(grav + a v^2 Cos[v t]) Sin[y[t]], 
      y'[0] == k, y[0] == j}, y[t], t][[1]];
  PendulumSol = y[t] /. pend;
  Plot[PendulumSol, {t, 0, param}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[r, g, b]]
  ]
(*
l_ = l; a_ = a ; v_ = v;  k_ = y'[0]; j=y[0]; param_ = time \
extention for plot
*)
sol[1, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 20
sol[1, 0, 0, 0.01, Pi, 20]
```

For the first boundary condition the function finds the solution and plots it while in the second case I get the following message:

[image: Error]

What am I missing here?

Thanks to every one who will be so keen to help

Comment: Try with Exact numbers. 980665/100000 and 1/100

Comment: that works.... Do you know what is the nature of this issue?

Comment: `Solve` is a symbolic solver. For numeric solvers see `NSolve` and `FindRoot`.